# SSAS Cube showing irrelevant ID

Tags: ssas, mdx

I write a calculation MDX formula to show ID and the sum of any one ID. But its showing Sum of one ID and showing like bellow. Where I should show only 1   10.

After sum in the DB there are:

```
1  10, 
2  30,
3  29,
4  97
```

I should show only 1  10
But its showing:

```
1  10,
2  10,
3  10,
4  10
```

I mean how many ID I have, its showing all of them. The ID is in Dimension.
anyone please help?

Comment: can you post your query please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You writed calculation MDX formula with set of Dimension `ID` where this `ID` is equal 10. So MDX always show same value if yours "filtered" Dimension is inserted. If you try to insert Dimension which is not in mdx formula (must be connected to measure group) you will see what mdx calculation value is divided.

Comment: Both measure and Dimension is connected with each other. Since I am filtering so it should show me only the filtered values, why all? If I want to show only the filtered value, what to do?

Comment: here is my MDX code
([Dataset].[Id].&[1], [Measures].[Gross Sale])

Comment: Yes, they are, so, because you using one filtered value `([Dataset].[Id].&[1], [Measures].[Gross Sale])`, cube doesn't respond to others values of this dimension. It's the rule. If you set that this calculated Measure is equal to this  `([Dataset].[Id].&[1], [Measures].[Gross Sale])` it not should respond to other Dimension Values.

Comment: I want that cube should not show.
it should show me only 1  10, not all ID, like 1  10,
2  10,
3  10,
4  10
. please see above

Comment: I think this is impossible, I can suggest what you rename your calculated Measure to "Gross Sale of 1 ID" and remove Dimension from your view application. Then it would be just Measure.